# What song is played during Attack on Titan season 3 episode 40 when Erwin is telling his story?

Tags: music, attack-on-titan

It's the background song that plays when he's telling the Commander his childhood story. Specifically the part I want to know about happens from 18:52-19:23. It sounds familiar to another song that may be used in AoT as well, albeit slowed down maybe?

Full song seems to be from 18:02-20:50

Answer (score 1):

Well I figured it out. It's "Attack on D" from Disc 1 of the Season 2 OST. Track 7 I believe. It seems slightly modified but it's definitely the same song. The specific part I mentioned being at 18:52-19:23 is actually the same part of Attack on D from 00:52-1:23, just with certain layers of audio excluded.